# Disable "save image" in iOS web application

Tags: ipad, web-applications

I want to disable the "save image" menu in mobile web applications that appears when you hold down a finger on an image. I tried the CSS properties:

```
-webkit-user-select: none;
-webkit-touch-callout: none;
```

With "-webkit-user-select" the copy menu is disabled but not the one for saving images. "-webkit-touch-callout" seems not to be working (tried on iPad2).

I also tried this javascript:

```
$('img').live('touchstart,touchmove,touchend', function() {
  event.preventDefault();
});
```

But without any effect.

Any suggestions?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: I just realized that I should try a different browser. I'm developing with iCab. When I try "-webkit-touch-callout: none;" in Safari it's working... but would be nice to find a solution for iCab as well.

Comment: Just a hint: when binding multiple events at the same time, you should separate the them with spaces, not with commas: http://api.jquery.com/bind/#multiple-events

Comment: `-webkit-touch-callout` is working for me. I used it on the `body` instead of the `img`

Answer (score 29):

I believe in this case [pointer-events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events) is your friend.
You can simply add:

```
<img src="path/to/image.png" style="pointer-events:none" alt="">
```

And you should be good to go.

Comment: I cannot get this to work on an ipad using ios11.  It still allows a user to tap and hold, bringing up the dialog box where they can save the image to the device.

Comment: `pointer-events` comes with a cost of disabling any interaction with an element, so in many cases it's basically useless.

Answer (score 2):

Well one thing you could do is cover the image with a transparent `<div>` tag. This would prevent the user form "clicking" (touching) the image at all:

```
<div style="position:relative;">
  <img src="something.png">
  <div style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:1000"></div>
</div>
```

**Note that if you send images to the browser they can be saved**. This is just a workaround, a minor annoyance for anyone who *really* wants the images. If you can view it, you can copy/steal it.

Comment: Unfortunately this is not working. All other clicks are disabled but the context menu still appears. I tested in iCab and Atomic Lite.

Comment: @Tina: even if the context menu appears, the menu will only apply to the DIV, not the image. But if you want the context menu to not appear for the DIV either, simply do: <div oncontextmenu="return false" style="position:absolute;left:0px;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;z-index:1000"></div>

Answer (score 2):

`-webkit-touch-callout` is working for me. I used it on the `body` instead of the `img`

Answer (score 0):

nothing worked for me except of removing the long press gesture recogniser:

```
for (UIView *subView in self.webView.scrollView.subviews) {
    for (UIGestureRecognizer *recogniser in subView.gestureRecognizers) {
        if ([recogniser isKindOfClass:UILongPressGestureRecognizer.class]) {
            [subView removeGestureRecognizer:recogniser];
        }
    }
}
```